# How to speed-up sed that uses Regex on very large single cell BAM file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have the following simple script that tries to count
the tag encoded with "CB:Z" in [SAM/BAM file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAM_(file_format)#:%7E:text=The%20SAM%20format%20consists%20of,in%20a%20compressed%20binary%20representation.&text=Alignment%20sections%20have%2011%20mandatory,variable%20number%20of%20optional%20fields.):

```
samtools view -h small.bam |  grep "CB:Z:" |
    sed 's/.*CB:Z:\([ACGT]*\).*/\1/' |
    sort |
    uniq -c |
    awk '{print $2 " " $1}'
```

Typically it needs to process 40 million lines. That codes takes around 1 hour to finish.

This line `sed 's/.*CB:Z:\([ACGT]*\).*/\1/'` is very time consuming.
How can I speed it up?

The reason I used the Regex is that the "CB" tag column-wise position
is not fixed. Sometimes it's at column 20 and sometimes column 21.

Example BAM file can be found **[HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/64em1wc2riey7ty/small.bam?dl=0)**.

---

**Update**

Speed comparison on complete 40 million lines file:

My initial code:

```
real    21m47.088s
user    26m51.148s
sys 1m27.912s
```

James Brown's with AWK:

```
real    1m28.898s
user    2m41.336s
sys 0m6.864s
```

James Brown's with MAWK:

```
real    1m10.642s
user    1m41.196s
sys 0m6.484s
```

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output in your question so that we get better understanding of your question.

Comment: Please give some idea of what you mean by *"time consuming"*... 4 hours on a supercomputer or 4 seconds on a Raspberry Pi. Thank you.

Comment: @Mark Setchell, They did say 1 hour, presumably on something more middle ground.

Comment: *Maybe* you can optimize your regex a little bit.  But frankly, if you have a large file (40 million lines) that's taking a long time to process (1++ hour) ... then maybe you ought to consider something besides "sed".  Try awk ... or perl ... or try writing a Java, C++ or C# program that processes the file in-memory.

Comment: If very CPU-intensive, you could try doing it in parallel with **GNU Parallel** and the `-pipe` option `samtools ... | parallel -pipe .... | sort ...`

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated my post with example BAM file for download.

Comment: More useful would be a few lines of output from `samtools view`

Comment: You can combine the `grep` and `sed` into one `sed` call, which might help a little tiny bit.

Comment: How do you know it's `sed` that's time consuming? Did you run `time` on the pipeline?

Comment: @Shawn Yes. I did with `time`

Comment: You should include its output in your question, then.

Comment: @scamander, its always encouraged to post samples in form of text not in form of links or images please. Kindly do add your samples in text form in your post which you are passing to different shell tools to get output, this will make things clear and will give us chance to perform testing too on our systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another awk, pretty much like @tripleee's, I'd assume:

```
$ samtools view -h small.bam | awk '
match($0,/CB:Z:[ACGT]*/) {               # use match for the regex match
    a[substr($0,RSTART+5,RLENGTH-5)]++   # len(CB:z:)==5, hence +-5
}
END {
    for(i in a)
        print i,a[i]                     # sample output,tweak it to your liking
}'
```

Sample output:

```
...
TCTTAATCGTCC 175
GGGAAGGCCTAA 190
TCGGCCGATCGG 32
GACTTCCAAGCC 76
CCGCGGCATCGG 36
TAGCGATCGTGG 125
...
```

**Notice**: Your `sed 's/.*CB:Z:...` matches the last instance where as my `awk 'match($0,/CB:Z:[ACGT]*/)...` matches the first.

**Notice 2**: Quoting @Sundeep in the comments: *- - using `LC_ALL=C mawk '..'` will give even better speed.*

Answer (score 3):

With `perl`

```sh
perl -ne '$h{$&}++ if /CB:Z:\K[ACGT]++/; END{print "$_ $h{$_}\n" for keys %h}'
```

`CB:Z:\K[ACGT]++` will match any sequence of `ACGT` characters preceded by `CB:Z:`. `\K` is used here to prevent `CB:Z:` from being part of matched portion, which is available via `$&` variable

Sample time with `small.bam` input file. `mawk` is fastest for this input, but it might change for larger input file.

```sh
# script.awk is the one mentioned in James Brown's answer
# result here shown with GNU awk
$ time LC_ALL=C awk -f script.awk small.bam > f1
real    0m0.092s

# mawk is faster compared to GNU awk for this use case
$ time LC_ALL=C mawk -f script.awk small.bam > f2
real    0m0.054s

$ time perl -ne '$h{$&}++ if /CB:Z:\K[ACGT]++/; END{print "$_ $h{$_}\n" for keys %h}' small.bam > f3
real    0m0.064s

$ diff -sq <(sort f1) <(sort f2)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
$ diff -sq <(sort f1) <(sort f3)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to avoid parsing the output of `samtools view` in the first place. Here's one way to get what you need just using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and the [pysam](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library:

```
import pysam

from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)
tag = 'CB'

with pysam.AlignmentFile('small.bam') as sam:
    for aln in sam:
        if aln.has_tag(tag):
            counts[ aln.get_tag(tag) ] += 1

for k, v in counts.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your original pipeline approach:

```sh
pcre2grep -o 'CB:Z:\K[^\t]*' small.bam |
 awk '{++c[$0]} END {for (i in c) print i,c[i]}'
```

In case you're interested in trying to speed up `sed` (although it's not likely to be the fastest):

```sh
sed 't a;s/CB:Z:/\n/;D;:a;s/\t/\n/;P;d' small.bam |
 awk '{++c[$0]} END {for (i in c) print i,c[i]}'
```

<sub>above syntax is compatible with GNU sed.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

regrading the AWK based solutions, i've noticed few taking advantage of FS.

I'm not too familiar with BAM format. If CB only show up once per line, then

```
mawk/mawk2/gawk -b 'BEGIN { FS = "CB:Z:"; 

   } $2 ~ /^[ACGT]/ {     # if FS never matches, $2 would be beyond
                          # end of line, then this would just match
                          # against  null string, & eval to false

      seen[substr($2, 1, -1 + match($2, /[^ACGT]|$/))]++ 

   } END { for (x in seen) { print seen[x] " " x } }'
```

If it shows up more than once, then change that to a loop of any field greater than 1. This version uses the laziest evaluation model possible to speed it up, then do all the uniq -c item.

While this is rather similar to the best answer above, by having FS pre-split the fields, it causes match() and substr() to do a lot less work. I'm simply matching 1 single char after the genetic sequence, and directly using its return, minus 1, as the substring length, and skipping RSTART or RLENGTH all together.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding :

```
$ diff -sq <(sort f1) <(sort f2)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
$ diff -sq <(sort f1) <(sort f3)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 are identical
```

there's absolutely no need to have them physically output to disk and do a diff. Just simply have the output of each piped to a very high speed hashing algorithm that adds close to no time (when the output is gigantic enough you might end up saving time versus going to disk.

my personal favorite is xxhash in 128-bit mode, available via python pip. it's *NOT* a cryptographic hash, but it's much faster than even something like MD5. This method also allows for hassle-free compare since the benchmark timing of it will also perform the accuracy check.